# Is bifunctor $\hom_C(\cdot,\cdot)$ non-degenerated

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

Assume that $C$ is a an additive category and $X,Y$ are objects in $C$ such that for any object $Z$ in $C$
$$\hom_C(X,Z)\cong\hom_C(Y,Z)$$
as groups.

> **Q.** Does it imply that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic objects in $C$.
>
> **Q+.** If not, how about $C$ being the category of $R$ modules for some commutative unitial ring $R$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the isomorphism is natural in $Z$, then yes, this is true since the Yoneda embedding is fully faithful. This is an immediate consequence of the Yoneda lemma. Note that in this case we only require the natural isomorphism to be one of sets, i.e. we regard the $\mathrm{hom}$-functor to be $\mathrm{Set}$-valued. But since isomorphic groups are in particular isomorphic sets, this does not make any difference here as far as I know.

In fact this is true in any locally small category (that is, in one where $\mathrm{hom}_C(X,Y)$ is a set).

Comment: Thank you. I will study Yoneda Lemma one more time then.